# Navigating to a section of a page using a reactstrat button's action

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, reactstrap

Typically if I want to make a link to go to a part of a page I use:

```
<a style={{ color: 'white' }} href="#topOfPage">
        Personal Info
</a>
```

Since I have to use Button from reactstrap (https://reactstrap.github.io/components/buttons/) instead of < a > I need to ask how to do the same within the action method of a button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. Try coding it this way:

   ```
   <Button tag={Link} style={{ color: 'white' }} to="#topOfPage" />
   ```

   You can utilize the same anchor tag href functionality with reactstraps buttons.
2. Another option, if the above does not work, would to be add the [Bootstrap node_module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) and code it the way you always have. I tend to mix reactstrap and bootstraps npmjs modules in my projects for faster coding.